# Triggering an orchestration after its failure in Biztalk 2009

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-orchestrations

I have an orchestration in BizTalk 2009 which has failed due to this error:

> Error:Transformation failed..,
>       StackTrace:    at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.ApplyStreamingTransform(Type
>    mapRef, TransformMetaData trfMetaData, Object[] outParams, Stream[] inStreams, Boolean whitespaceCorrect)

I don't know the reason behind that. But is it possible to trigger that orchestration and how? Taking into consideration that tracking is not enabled.

Comment: That error means that a map failed.  Without further details of where you are executing that map, what the input message and details of your Orchestration we can't really help you debug this.  Also how do you mean trigger on orchestration?

Comment: Are you asking how you can trigger an orchestration on failure of a message on a port?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're asking - my first guess is that you want to reprocess the message (something like resume a suspended instance), but do you mean that you just want to send a test message into it?  If the former, the message would just cause the same error - if the latter, the question is a bit too broad...  Make an attempt and see if you come up with a more specific question.  See also [mcve]

Comment: what is the down voting for, i am new to biztalk thats why my question may seem unclear?

Comment: Yes the downvote is probably due to your question being unclear.  Try and address the issues raised by Dan and I and edit your question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when one looks at BizTalk Orchestration failures the message contained within the BizTalk Group Hub page can be limited.

From the message you psoted "Error:Transformation failed.., StackTrace: at " this means the map failed as already established. If you want more context on the issue open up the event viewer on the server itself and find the event. This will often give a much more extensive output.

In my experience this is typically a functoid of some sort that has fallen over and the best debugging method here, from an abstract perspective, is divide and conquer, attempt to get the message that is being used and run it through the same map used within the transform shape within your orchestration.